# Should I separate properties and methods in partial classes?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm writing the foundational classes for an application, and want to construct them properly for long term maintainability.  To that end, I'm researching which design patterns to implement, use of interfaces, abstract classes, and separating persistence from activity.  My head is swimming with patterns, paradigms, and principles.

I have a class `Product` for which I have created an interface `IProduct`.  I believe I need to make `Product` and abstract class, because any instance of it is required to be one of half a dozen values for the property `Category`.  So, my first question: is the following the appropriate way to do that?

```
abstract class Product : IProduct
{
    // Fields
    // Properties
    // Methods
}

interface IProduct
{
    // Properties
}

public class Model : IProduct
{
    public Model()
    {
        Category = "Model";
    }

    // Model-specific fields
    // Model-specific properties
    // Model-specific methods
}
```

Articles I read, including questions previously answered here, indicate that I should design with separation of properties and methods (persistence and activity).  To that end, should the above code really look like this?

```
abstract class Product : IProduct
{
    // Fields
    // Properties
    // Methods
}

interface IProduct
{
    // Properties
}

public partial class Model : IProduct
{
    public Model()
    {
        Category = "Model";
    }

    // Model-specific fields
    // Model-specific properties
}

public partial class Model : IProduct
{
    // Model-specific methods
}
```

Of course, that presumes I got the first part right, but perhaps the answers will enlighten me on how I should be doing things.

Lastly, if separation of properties and methods is a good thing, and `Product` has some methods that are applicable across all concrete versions of it, should I move them to a separate abstract class like this?

```
abstract class Product : IProduct
{
    // Fields
    // Properties
}
abstract class Product : IProduct
{
    // Methods
}
```

Comment: I personally have never felt the need to create multiple partial classes to separate properties and methods.  I don't get it. You could go even further and start separating the public interface from the private in yet more partial classes.  I think this does nothing but make the code *harder* to maintain by adding a bunch of useless cognitive overhead.  Have fun jumping between files/many lines just to understand the flow of a given function. Just keep things separated within the class definition logically and be consistent.

Comment: "*persistence and activity*" - I think this is the "java-way" of handling it: Having Entities (*dumb data-structures*) and services (*work with entities*). In C# i never seperated those - and at the end it is just personal preference, if you would like to call `user.Save()` or `userService.Save(user);`

Comment: All depends on what you're after. Is it targeted to be a UI-based application, or by "foundational", you mean a framework-like code-base?

Comment: I don't understand the snippets above too well. What are you using your abstract `Product` class for? It seems like you create an abstract class to implement some of the members required by `IProduct`, then completely ignore it and implement the interface from scratch in the concrete `Model` class. Since C# doesn't have multiple inheritance, there's no way to work `Product` into the inheritance hierarchy once you've already implemented everything in `IProduct` from scratch in your concrete class.

Comment: Should you? No. But that is my opinion. Design a contract (interface) and implement the concrete version (class). fin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only use I see in keeping `partial` classes is when two separate systems update the two files. This is true for example when using Visual Studio designers (the Windows Forms designer for instance), that update their own class file. Another thing could be true for another auto-generated class you have. One is maintained by the system, one by you.

I never ever felt the urge to have two separate `partial` class files I maintain myself. I usually use `#region` directives to split the methods and the properties.

Comment: The use of `#region`s is preferably to be avoided: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/53114/14244

Comment: @WillMarcouiller I agree on the use of regions inside methods, but in classes I don't see the problem.

Comment: How well do you find that works in an environment where multiple developers are working on the same code?  Historically, any time I've written code (which is rarely), I've been the sole developer.  In this situation, I'm sharing space with an actual professional developer, with me acting as the analyst and software architect.  We're already colliding with one another as he works on the persistence bits (EF) while I work on the business layer.

Comment: We use a decent version control system that does merge pretty good. I have never had any issues, and I have a few people working for me.

Comment: My own preference is to use partial classes to separate nested types from the rest of the class.  I also never use `#region` directives as I don't find them to be that helpful when reading code (even code written by others; I actually find them to be a nuisance, but that's just my preference).

Comment: Persistence layer and business layer shouldn't be *the same code*.

Comment: In fact, only because they require more work from the developer and provide no real value to the quality of the software. One shouldn't rely on regions to organize one's code, and instead make smaller classes and properly named methods, the shorter the better, so it is concise and the other programmers who shall someday have to read the code can see from the first sight what is the intention behind the code. Regions just hide this and come to interfere with this comprehensiveness.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller I use regions to separate properties, methods, and constructors. I don't use them within code blocks, just at the class level It helps to navigate a large code file, and isn't an antipattern like using regions inside a method would be (you should instead split the method into separate methods if they're that big).

Comment: @mason each of those pieces of code only need a new-line separator. This shall be enough to show the intention. Everyone can recognize what's a field, what's a method and what's a property, why adding some futile code for it?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller: Indeed. If you don't like regions, don't use them. Use a line break instead :) .

Comment: @PatrickHofman, I like your comment! =)

Comment: @WillMarcouiller It's not that you can't recognize it. It's an organizational thing and it helps you find what you're looking for quickly. If you open a file up and you know you're looking for a constructor, then it's nice to just be able to simply expand the Constructors region without having to examine all the methods. If you have a lot of similar methods, you can even group them together into separate groups. It's not a big thing, but it helps with the tidiness. And I don't like untidy code.

Comment: @mason, following DI rules, the constructor makes your dependencies obvious, and one of the thing that is the most important in coding, is to know your dependencies, so why don't you just make your constructor the first thing encountered in your file? And the least important, are the private fields, even for the variables that will hold references over your dependencies, so just put them at the complete bottom of your class. Now, generally speaking, public members are the one that may cause troubles to the other objects, so they are the most important, then make them follow the properties!

Comment: @WillMarcouiller A class can have more than one constructor. A method can have more than one overload. Feature richness is not linearly related to LOC, so it is possible for a class to be large and unwieldy to look at, but logically represent only the code required to carry out a single, sometimes even very simple, responsibility.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller See, I follow a completely different organization, which I feel strengthens the argument for using regions. If two people use different organizations for their code, then using regions will assist the other person in locating what they're looking for. (I like to see what properties a class contains, so I put fields/properties at the top,  then constructors, then static methods, then regular methods).

Comment: @Asad: You can have a many constructors as you like! Just put them on top! You may have as many as overloads as you like, just group them together, that's it! Plus, overloads often calls a single simple method at the end, because one method shall have a single responsibility, but multiple entry points which are represented by the overloads. If you have to write two different piece of code for two overloads of the same method, this ends with a design smell. Overloads should only be used when it makes sens to call a method with a different type of argument, that is why they are recognized assuch

Comment: @WillMarcouiller "You may have as many as overloads as you like, just group them together". Well yes, this is exactly what I'm doing with regions. My constructors are also always at the top, grouped together using a region. That way I can collapse them when I don't want to think about construction and dependency injection stuff.

Comment: And regions hide the overloads from the programmer who needs to read the code. Why use region if your class fits in one screen, private fields included? Everyone can see what's going on with 3 methods of the same name, it adds no **real** value to use regions. Instead of adding lines of code with regions, reduce the number of lines by removing them and making your code more functional. A method can often hold on a single line, especially for overloads which only call the method they overload with the proper type of argument. Otherwise your methods may end up doing more than a single resp.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller That's such a short-sighted opinion. I don't want to ever read a codebase where the devs tried to fit every class within one screen.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller I've never written code trivial enough that everything was one line. Sure I could take a four line, two statement inner block for loop and turn it into a separate method that performs the work for each iteration, and another method that accepts the number of iterations and error handlers as arguments, and then finally replace the for loop with an invocation of this. Now I've got all the overhead of passing around information the was readily available in the scope, the multiline overhead of declaring a method, matching up parameter and return types, etc. etc. Why?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller: In cases where a many overloads of a function chain to a common implementation (common when a function has some seldom-used "optional" parameters), I'd generally rather see the definition of the "real" function, followed by a collapsed region containing the "helper" overloads, than have to scroll over lots of chaining-overload definitions between that function and the next "real" one.  The overloads belong with the main function, but much of the time they're just visual noise.

Comment: @supercat: You made your point, here. This might in fact be a relatively good use of the regions, although I prefer not to use them and see at first sight that they are overloads without having to expand a region at all. I believe that it is now a matter of personal preference. =)

Comment: @Asad: Simple! For the sake of code readability. If you explode your code such as it is self-documentary, you will gain much more from writing easily understandable code which speaks for itself what it actually does than what you lose as function call overhead in performance, with the powerful machines we have to day. How many hours can one lose trying to understand another's code sometimes? Even though it's just as simple as `if (value == null)`, why is it bad for it to be null? What is the functional intention behind? Of course, this is perhaps a too simple example, and I guess u understand.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller: The problem with splitting out methods isn't just one of CPU costs.  In many cases, a piece of code that can make certain assumptions about things will be much smaller than a general-purpose piece of code.  Having a piece of code appear within the context where it is used can help make it obvious to anyone looking at it that the assumptions will hold, and to anyone working on the surrounding code that the assumptions are being relied upon.  Seeing a method or a method call in isolation would make such things less clear.

Comment: @supercat: Agreed, although this is also a matter of balance. Just don't refactor every single line of code to another method if this doesn't make sense. Besides, a method with lots of lines can also bear more responsibility than it should, so does, within the iteration, respect the single responsibility principle? And that is what matters the most, because based on your definition of the SRP, since it is only a principle, this is very subjective, and one can come across misinterpretation of the concept behind it, thus the questions one has to ask oneself.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller: Many discussions of programming assume a strong correlation between how users of a library should see things and the arrangement of source code in the library.  For libraries that straddle application layers, it's very common for a method which can be described concisely to make a complicated sequence of calls to many methods, all of which present a much more complex view to their caller than the outer method does to its.  In many cases, a method "GetCustomerName(String CustomerId)" might call several "nice" methods which each try to find out the customer name, but...

Comment: ...sometimes it may be necessary to have one's selection of fallback strategies depend upon the internals of what went wrong on the initial attempt to find the name.  Further, while one would generally have a `GetCustomerName` method delegate to a more general `GetCustomerInfo` record, there may be some resources which wouldn't have full info for a customer but would have names, and might be available when the full-info resources aren't.  If clients will often benefit from being able to get a customer's name even when other info is unavailable, it may be helpful to provide for that.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer combining semantic-based and visibility-based approach to sorting members within a class. Actually I don't know who ever 'invented' the rule to sort out members based on the type of language entity (i.e. fields in a group, properties in a group etc.) That makes hardly any sense in respect to readability.

It is a good idea to use `#region` directives to separate them. Also, I tend to use horizontal lines (`------…---`) to make the code more readable.

Example:

```
public class SomeClass : ParentClass, ISomeInterface
{
    #region ------ Large feature 1 ----------------------------
    … // any non-private members related to 'Large feature 1' go here
    #endregion

    #region ------ Large feature 2 ----------------------------
    … // any non-private members related to 'Large feature 2' go here
    #endregion

    #region ------ Implementation of ISomeInterface -----------
    … // ISomeInterface implementation goes here, comments are *not* repeated
    #endregion

    #region ------ ParentClass overrides ----------------------
    … // parent class members' overrides go here, comments are *not* repeated
    #endregion

    #region ------ Internals ----------------------------------
    … // any private members, i.e. the actual implementation
    #endregion
}
```

There is no reason to over-use partial declarations unless you really need to have them in separate files. A good reason is when a portion of the class is auto-generated. However, using partial declarations for the sole sake of separating members is far less readable and maintainable than consistent use of regions.

Also, I'm not a fan of separating property declarations and corresponding backing field declarations (in case you can't use auto-properties). The following is far more maintainable and readable:

```
public int SomeProperty
{
    get { … return someProperty; }
    set { someProperty = value; … }
}
private int someProperty;
```

Comment: It would certainly be much simpler and make your code cleaner if you put those "large features" in a class of their own following the SRP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Honestly, it would certainly be a good idea to admit software engineering is a broad field solving a broad range of problems where one size **does not** fit all. I'm not paying developers for overengineering things but for producing working, clean, adequately complex code without preventing juniors / less-skilled devs / new kids on the blcok to joining the team without extreme pain (and costs) :-)

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Feel free to assume `SomeClass` = `Customer`, 'Large feature 1' = 'Identification data such as First name, Last name, Nick', 'Large feature 2' = 'Contacts such as address, email, IM name' or whatever else which is clearly not contradicting SRP.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Sometimes this approach makes no sense, for example when I am grouping overloads or constructors together. I can't move overloads or constructors to another class.

Comment: @Asad: Agreed. And therefore constructors should only make sure the class receives its dependencies, and that they are non-null, so that they can be assigned to the variables holding the references to those dependencies, and that is all what a constructor should do, initialize the class. If you have a constructor with more than four arguments, then questions should begin to tackle your mind like "does my constructor do too much things"? I rarely have a constructor with more than 10 lines of code, that is including the null-guard clauses for each of the parameters with an if on two lines.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Generally, from a design purity perspective you are right. However, I would recommend studying some real-world code ;-)

Comment: @WillMarcouiller I often have a constructor that accepts a single reference type representing the set of all its dependencies and stores it, as well as overloads that accept the individual dependencies and inject these into a new instance of the "aggregate" dependency type, before passing this on to the single argument constructor. This makes any consuming code cleaner and less annoying to write. Is this feature creep? Is my class more complex now and in need of being broken up into multiple modules?